# What decides whether an ulcer/chancre is painful or painless?

Tags: microbiology, pathology, pathogenesis

In sexually transmitted infections, it is important to differentiate a painful ulcer from a painless one. This is because painless ulcers are seen in the chancre of primary syphilis while painful tender ones are seen in Herpes and though rare, in chancroid (*H. ducreyi*).

I can guess that it must be due to peripheral nerves, but how does this happen?

Comment: My hat's off to you. Not only have I never wondered about this, but having consulted Cecil's, Harrison's, several neurology texts, and other scholarly sources, not a single source addresses this.

Comment: It is small things like these that we generally ignore.. Thanks :') @anongoodnurse